# Woocommerce group products have show in related product area?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have wanted my group products images and add to cart button shown in related product area for user direct add them. And the view of single page product using Group Products is looking good. I have solved in product summary area image showing, but not solving "Woocommerce group products have shown in related product area?", this problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you try to rephrase it. Maybe include some screenshots if that would help.

Comment: @
helgatheviking I have want to display my group product as related product, Is it possible?

Comment: Related products are related by tag and/or category. So I presume if your single product and your group product share a tag/category they would end up as related. Do keep in mind that the related products is also random, so if you had a lot of products that shared the same terms it might not show. But otherwise, I don't see anything in the code that would prevent a grouped product from showing as related.